# Point Position texture is switched at Seams

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-baking, displacement

I baked *Position* pass, that works without issues for *Displacement* modifier.

[image]

When I use this texture in *Geometry Nodes* for *Set Position* node the result is OK, only vertices marked as *Seams* are positioned wrong. Vertical loop is mirrored and rotated, horizontal inner loop follows outer loop (= positions of middle UV loop).

[image]

I tried to scale down UV a bit (0.99) ... to test if Margin make some difference, but it didn't.
GN node-tree issue ...? Thanks :)

---

*File was big with texture ... so first press *Bake* for selected *Torus* object, than make visible "02..." object to see texture effect in  geometry node displacement ...*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to [a question I've answered yesterday](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279463/how-to-displace-the-surface-of-a-sphere-with-an-image-avoiding-seam-in-geometry/279581#279581), this seems to be a domain interpolation problem. You're using a *UVMap*, which is in *Face Corner* domain, to drive values in *Point* domain so you get double values where the two ends of the baked image meets (seams). Sticking an `Interpolate Domain` node in *Face Corner* mode (*Face* also works) between the image and the vector math solves the problem:

[image]

Comment: Great :) Thanks a lot ... Haven't seen it.